# Invalid content was found starting with the element 'simple'. Camel Issues

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, dsl

My requirement is to poll a database for every few minutes and get a sql. Hence my code is

```
 <camel:route>

        <camel:from uri="timer:dataRetrieve?period=5s"/> 

          <camel:to uri="sql:select output_obj,create_dt,destination_type from dbo.gcas_events_test where process_sw = 'N' order by create_dt desc" />


        </camel:route>
```

I am expecting 3 fields from my data set. I want to see if the destination_type='SEC' then it has to go to a different route.

So I came up with.

```
    <camel:route>

                <camel:from uri="timer:dataRetrieve?period=5s"/> 

                  <camel:to uri="sql:select output_obj,create_dt,destination_type from dbo.gcas_events_test where process_sw = 'N' order by create_dt desc" />
                <camel:choice>
                       <camel:when>
                             <simple>${body.destination_type}='SEC'</simple>
                             <camel:to uri="foo" />
                        </camel:when>

                    </camel:choice>

                </camel:route>
```

And it throws an error at the simple tag. Similar problem with ognl too. What am i doing wrong here? Also will `${body.destination_type}='SEC'` work? (assuming I have that value in the data set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Camel doc](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html), the output of a select statement is a `List<Map<String, Object>>` if not configured differently. In your case, the first `destination_type` found in your result set can be accessed as follows:

```
${body[0][destination_type]}
```

The route definition should be as follows (use `==` instead of a simple `=`):

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="timer:dataRetrieve?period=5s"/> 
    <camel:to uri="sql:select output_obj,create_dt,destination_type from dbo.gcas_events_test where process_sw = 'N' order by create_dt desc" />
    <camel:choice>
        <camel:when>
            <camel:simple>${body[0][destination_type]} == 'SEC'</simple>
            <camel:to uri="foo" />
        </camel:when>
    </camel:choice>
</camel:route>
```

If every record of the result set should be handled one by one, then you may use a [splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html):

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="timer:dataRetrieve?period=5s"/> 
    <camel:to uri="sql:select output_obj,create_dt,destination_type from dbo.gcas_events_test where process_sw = 'N' order by create_dt desc" />
    <camel:split>
        <camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple>
        <camel:choice>
            <camel:when>
                <camel:simple>${body[destination_type]} == 'SEC'</simple>
                <camel:to uri="foo" />
            </camel:when>
        </camel:choice>
    </camel:split>
</camel:route>
```